# display image/jpeg in img with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say http://example.com/image returns generated image data as image/jpeg with some additional data in response headers. http://example.com/image returns generated image different for each request. Image generation is somewhat random (or at least it's independent from a request). Response comes with additional data like creation time (but not only).

What i need to do is make some operations on data from headers and display the image. The problem I'm having is with displaying the image together with the headers. Let's say i want to display the image and print the response's headers just below the image. How can i do that?

I retrieve the image using `angularjs` and `$http`. And then I have

```
var imagedata = response.data
var someheader = response.header('some-header')
```

From here, how do i display the `imagedata`?
All I found is to convert data to base64. Is there a way to avoid such conversion?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I'm looking for something that would work for older browsers like ie8/9. I know that there is `URL.createObjectURL`. But that doesn't seem compatible.

Comment: simply no you have to convert it; if you can share response with header there may be;

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What kind of data is coming in the headers? What would you want to do with the data? How does it affect how you will display the image?

Comment: @Martin http://example.com/image returns generated image different for each request. Every image comes with some metadata sent in headers. Because of that I can't simply put url in img tag, because then I wouldn't have a way to retrieve metadata.

Comment: So, if I understand, you are trying to make something similar to http://placehold.it - where you generate images on the fly using data passed to the request? Difference being that you specifically do not want the data to be passed in the URL, but rather through the request headers, right?

Comment: @Martin almost. Image generation is somewhat random (or at least it's independent from a request). Response comes with additional data like creation time (but not only).

Comment: Okay. I feel like this is not a frontend but a backend issue. Handling HTTP requests is the job of the server, not the client. Can you illustrate a use case for me?

Comment: @Martin The request is handled perfectly. The problem I'm having is with displaying the image together with the headers. `http://example.com/image` returns different image with different headers for every request. Let's say i want to display the image and print the response's headers just below the image. How can i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107770/discussion-between-martin-and-tuan-pham).

Answer (score 1):

If you're including the image inline in the IMG tag, you must convert to base64.  The reason for this is that binary image data could contain any number of characters and symbols that are not valid in HTML.

Imagine that whatever image data you insert will become part of the HTML/DOM of hte page - including whatever quotes, double-quotes, greater/less than signs are within the binary image data.

MORE INFO:
In Javascript, it would look like this:

```
encodedImage = window.btoa(binaryimagedata);

newimg = Document.createElement('img')
newimg.src = "data:text/css;base64,"+encodedImage
document.body.appendChild
```

Comment: How can an image with content type image/jpeg contain anything else than binary data? Can you show some example?

Comment: It won't.  You _must_ convert it to Base64 before pushing it to the HTML/DOM.

Comment: Ok, so let me rephrase the question. Is there any other way to display the image than _including the image inline in the IMG tag_?

Comment: You're doing this client-side with Javascript, correct?  An HTML image can only point to an external file or embed the image data inline.  I've updated my answer with JS code to show how this would work.  If you're doing the work server-side, then you could just point to the generated image directly (or the image-generating script).

Comment: I am trying this but still does not seem to work, however i had to change my code to something like this;

var b64Response = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(res.data)));
                this.setState({imageContent: "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+b64Response});

and my img is like;

<img src={this.state.imageContent} />